# Should I always use the new operator in C++ instead of the malloc function?

Tags: c++, malloc, new-operator

```
struct A
{
 string st;
};

int main()
{
 A *a = (A *)malloc(sizeof(A));
 a->st = "print";

 cout << a->st;
 return 0;
}
```

When I use this way and it compiled successfully, but after that in runtime I got exception. So, I figure out one thing is `A *a = new A;` instead of `A *a = (A *)malloc(sizeof(A));`. Which way is better and without error for doing this type of things?

What should I do for runtime memory allocation?

Comment: You ***must*** use `new` in c++, otherwise your code has undefined behavior.

Comment: `malloc` does not invoke the constructor, only allocates memory. So your object is uninitialized and accessing it is UB. You should avoid `malloc` in c++ and use `new`, or even better as mentioned above - do not use dynamic allocation at all if possible.

Comment: Generally, you can use `malloc` instead of the [`new` _operator_](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new); however, you cannot use `malloc` instead of the [`new` _expression_](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new).

Comment: Can you share which C++ textbook discussed using `malloc` in C++ code? No, no C++ textbook does that. This kind of question only comes up as a result of attempting to use Google as a replacement for a good C++ textbook. Unfortunately, Google is not a replacement for a C++ textbook.

Comment: Curios - does this always throw a runtime error? I'm thinking it should, in theory but I got it running in an online compiler (if I added `#include <iostream>` and `using namespace std;` at the top) without errors and it did output "print". (Specifically https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler)

Comment: I can see why this question was asked. The code is very close to the first example code in https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/arrow-operator-in-c-c-with-examples/ except for the line that initially creates the object and sets it to NULL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`malloc` alone is outright wrong. `malloc` allocates memory, it does **not** create objects.

`new` allocates memory and creates an object by calling the constructor.

The "better" way is to not use either of the two when there is no reason to use them.

```
int main() {
   A a;
   a.st = "print";
   cout << a.st;
}
```

`A` has only a single member of type `std::string`. `std::string` is already managing a dynamically allocated character string. There is no reason to dynamically allocate a `std::string`, and also no reason to use `new` to create an `A`.

If you still need to dynamically allocate an object you should not use raw owning pointers. Your code leaks memory and there is no trivial fix for that (a `delete` at the end of `main` may never be reached when an exception is thrown). Use smart pointers when you do need to dynamically allocate an object.

Comment: Malloc isn’t totally wrong, but you do have to construct your objects (with some exceptions in C++20), and you have to  destruct the objects (not strictly true but yikes) and `free` the `malloc`ed memory. So just use `new` and `delete`. Or better: use `std::make_unique`.